# Firebase DebugView not showing events on Android

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

**Update:** seems like it was a temporary issue on firebase and it works now.

**Original post:**

I configured my app to work with Firebase analytics and trying to see the events in the `DebugView` dashboard.

This worked fine for me on the first day - some of the times it didn't recognise the device and I needed to refresh, but mostly it was ok.
Now when I start my app is see this line in the log

> I/FA: Faster debug mode event logging enabled. To disable, run:
>         adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app .none.

I believe that it means that the `DebugView` is configured correctly - but i don't see anything there.

More than that - I see the events in the general events view, and as far as I can understand debug events aren't supposed to be sent there.

Any idea what might be the problem? I thought I might have mistyped the package name - but if I get the message that the `Faster debug event logging` is enabled - I assume that this error is irrelevant.

Comment: I faced the same problem today, but on iOS. Events, instead of being displayed on the `DebugView` panel, are displayed on the `StreamViev` panel after some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're many reports in Firebase Google Group. Seems like the team is fixing it

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/debugview%7Csort:date/firebase-talk/nmG8IcVi16Y/wbjjHg67BwAJ

Comment: The response from the firebase team is regarding seeing item details in debug view - this isn't about actually seeing items at all.

But I do see that ppl are reporting on this same issue from the last few days - hope it will be solved

Comment: As I said - the issue you linked isn't the same one, but I guess there was some general problem in debug view that is fixed now